# Залогировать url на который отправлен запрос nginx

Tags: nginx

Как залогировать полный урл, на который был отправлен запрос?

Нужно добавить лог, в котором будет `$proxy_host + $path`

Сейчас лог имеет формат:

```
{
        "@timestamp":"2024-01-22T08:42:44+00:00",
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "remote_addr":"10.109.21.13",
        "status":"404",
        "method":"GET",
        "path":"/my/path/?qr=12",
        "request_time":"0.307",
        "query_params":"qr=12",
        "cookie":"",
        "proxy_host":"foo.ru",
        "upstream_addr":"<IP>:443",
        "http_referrer":"",
        "cleaned_referer":"",
        "http_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "env":"ya"
}
```

log.conf:

```
#logs
log_format main_json escape=json
'{'
'"@timestamp":"$time_iso8601",'
'"level": "DEBUG",'
'"remote_addr":"$remote_addr",'
'"status":"$status",'
'"method":"$request_method",'
'"path":"$request_uri",'
'"request_time":"$request_time",'
'"query_params":"$query_string",'
'"cookie":"$http_cookie",'
'"proxy_host":"$proxy_host",'
'"upstream_addr":"$upstream_addr",'
'"http_referrer":"$http_referer",'
'"cleaned_referer":"$cleaned_referer",'
'"http_user_agent":"$http_user_agent",','
'"env":"ya-ruc1-dev1",'
'}';
```

Comment: в формат добавить строку `'"full_path":"$proxy_host$request_uri",'`

Comment: а базовой переменной нет в nginx случайно, которая как-раз хронит эти данные?

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html, скорее всего нету